# Making ng-show/ng-hide work with localStorage being modified by external sources outside of Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is the top level controller for my login overlay.

```
login.controller('main_controller', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.shouldShowLoginOverlay = function () {
        return (null == localStorage.getItem("auth_token"));
    }
}]);
```

Here is the corresponding HTML.

```
<div ng-controller = "main_controller" ng-show="shouldShowLoginOverlay()"></div>
```

As soon as after logging in, I set auth_token in localstorage, the overlay automatically disappears.
I tried deleting the entry form chrome's resources section and even JS console using removeItem.
In that case the overlay doesn't appear automatically!
I am new to angular, what am I missing ?

Comment: removing the local storage from js console will not work you have to delete from code and then manually call a digest cycle using scope.$apply()

Comment: @Ajaybeniwal: what if a third party, deletes it from my localstorage?
I should come to know, right? is $watch a solution? or I have to subscribve inside my controller to localstoarge events using $on and call $apply on scope?
Or I am also seeing solutions where ppl use broadcaste.. whats the difference in the three approaches ?

Answer (score 1):

you can try something like this

```
view.html

<p align="center" ng-show="yourFunction() == true">will show when you had something valued as True on local storage</p>



controller.js

$scope.yourFunction = function() {
  return localStorage.getItem("your_local_storage")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`<div ng-controller = "main_controller" ng-show="isAuthenticated" ng-init="shouldShowLoginOverlay()"></div>`

And change the controller to :-

```
login.controller('main_controller', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.shouldShowLoginOverlay = function () {
      $scope.isAuthenticated  = (null == localStorage.getItem("auth_token"));
      return $scope.isAuthenticated;
    }
}]);
```

Also I recommend use of Services or Factories to implement a login authentication module.

Comment: Would he need to call $scope.apply() to get angular to know?

Answer (score 0):

A different solution to the problem can be tried by adding classes to the overlay. Something like,
`.show {
    display: block;
}
.hide {
    display: none;
}`
I have a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nkanand4/t79hx/) for you.

Answer (score 0):

Pls try below Dummy Code

```
<body ng-controller="test">
    <div ng-show="istrue">fadf</div>
    <input type="button" ng-click="addItem()" value="add" />
    <input type="button" ng-click="removeItem()" value="Remove" />
    <script>
        var myApp = angular.module("MyApp", ["ngAnimate"]);
        myApp.controller('test', function ($scope) {
            alert(localStorage.getItem("auth_token"));
            $scope.$watch(function () {
                return (null != localStorage.getItem("auth_token"));
            }, function (newvalue, oldvalue) {
                $scope.istrue=newvalue
            });

            $scope.addItem = function () {
                var testObject = { 'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three': 3 };
                localStorage.setItem('auth_token', JSON.stringify(testObject));
            }
            $scope.removeItem = function () {
                localStorage.removeItem('auth_token');
            }

        });


    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: wont work if external elements modify loclastorage. watch wont be called!